# Overload a C++ assignment operator to behave like Java

Tags: java, c++, assignment-operator

In Java, when you assign one object to another, the original object isn't copied, it merely clones the reference. So, for example, I'd like it to behave like this Java code:

```
SomeClass x = new SomeClass();
SomeClass y;
y = x; // x is not copied, y is simply a (Java) reference to x
```

What I'd like to do is create a C++ class that behaves the same way. The obvious choice is to overload the assignment operator, like so:

```
SomeClass& operator=(const SomeClass& rhs)
{
    this = &rhs;
    return *this;
}
```

Unfortunately, assigning a new location to `this` is not allowed; the above code won't even compile.

Does anyone know of any other way to do this?

Also, before you say anything: yes, I know this is absolutely the wrong way to implement an assignment operator. Please, indulge me anyway.

EDIT 2: To clarify, here is the C++ code that should behave as in Java:

```
SomeClass x = SomeClass(); // Created on stack
SomeClass y; // In C++, same as above; NOT reference or pointer
y = x; // x is not copied, y becomes a (C++) reference to x;
       // original y is destroyed when stack unwinds
```

I DO NOT want to use pointers at all.

EDIT: I'm doing this to see if I can change the base address of a C++ object that was passed by reference to a function. If I simply assign another object to the reference variable, it automatically makes a shallow copy, and I don't want that. I want the reference parameter to reference a completely different object.

I'm doing this to see how references are implemented by the compiler. If references are syntactic sugar for dereferenced pointers, then outside the function, the base address of the argument object would NOT change. If they are aliases in the symbol table (as in PHP), then it WILL change. (So any solution using pointers is out, since that's my "control" for the test.)

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  In Java, `x` and `y` are, in essence, pointers (references).  So the assignment in Java changes the value of one of the pointers.  You can't do the same thing in C++ if the objects you're trying to assign aren't pointers.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to use pointers. It really is just reinventing the wheel that's built into the language.

Comment: @ajb: So what I want to do is not possible, then?

Comment: @chris: I'm editing the question to clarify what I would like to do.

Comment: If you look at both the implementation of a shared pointer, and the pointer-to-implementation idiom, you'll learn how to implement this....

Comment: @KarlGiesing There's a difference between "not possible" and "not conceivable".  "Not possible" would be "Bring me a cat with seven legs".  You couldn't do it, but at least we would have an idea of what I'm asking for.  "Not conceivable" would be "Bring me a cat that is also a dog"--that just doesn't make sense.  What you're asking is more like the second case.

Comment: @KarlGiesing More clarification: If you want to copy pointers, then your objects have to be declared as pointers.  If what you want is to copy a pointer to `SomeClass`, then an assignment that tries to assign to a `SomeClass` can't be right, since a `SomeClass` is not a pointer to a `SomeClass`.  If `SomeClass` is a pointer to _something else_, though, please clarify.

Comment: @ajb: hope the edit clarified what I'd like to do.

Comment: @KarlGiesing Regarding your edit:  C++ is a compiled language, not an interpreted language like PHP.  _There is no symbol table_, not once the program has been compiled and is running.  (Java is also a compiled language, but every variable you declare is automatically a pointer, except for primitive types.)  In C++, when you declare an object, the compiler decides where to put that object.  It can't change its mind at runtime.  If you want an object that can change its location, _you must explicitly use a pointer_.

Comment: @ajb, [Oh really](http://static1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130908022820/scratchpad/images/9/9c/1998_-_CatDog.jpg).

Comment: @chris Forgot all about that.  My kids used to watch that show.

Comment: @ajb: So, if I run nm on an executable file in Linux, what exactly am I looking at?

Comment: @KarlGiesing It will have symbols and addresses; for *global* variables and functions, it will have the addresses the linker has assigned to the variables.  Local variables won't have addresses.  Those will be determined when the function that owns them starts.  The address of a local will be somewhere on the stack, but it won't change as long as the function is executing.  The symbol table can be useful for debugging, but it usually is *not* present in memory while the program is running.

Comment: @ajb: I actually decompiled some very simple code, and it appears that you're not correct (for g++ at least). If you create a global reference, and pass that reference to a function, the caller first looks in the global symbol table and gets the base address of the reference. It appears that what is stored in the reference is the offset in the symbol table from the reference's address, not the base address of the referenced variable. I can post the disassembled code if you want. This probably doesn't apply to other compilers, of course.

Comment: @KarlGiesing I'd be interested in seeing the C++ code.  I can try compiling and disassembling it myself.  Thanks.

Comment: @ajb: I will send you the C++ and decompiled code privately. It's short for a C++ program, but still too long to post in a comment.

Comment: @ajb: Okay, I thought Stack Overflow allowed PM's. Apparently not. It's easy to write a simple C++ program, compile it, and use nm and objdump on the results; it helps if you make the variables static so they show up in the global symbol table. EDIT: I was wrong about the symbol table storing the offset, though. You actually get at the symbol table by offset from the instruction pointer, so I was confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible. The languages just work fundamentally differently.

`SomeClass x` in Java is some kind of pointer or reference to a SomeClass object. It's an indirection, so that why you can have multiple ones refering to the same object.

`SomeClass x` in C++ literally is the object. Thus `SomeClass y` is literally an entirely different object. There's no indirection. And so there's no way to make one reference the other.

C++ provides pointers (`SomeClass* x`) and references (`SomeClass& x`) to take care of the times when indirection is needed. Perhaps those are what you actually want to use, although it depends on why you asked this question in the first place.

---

Responding to the edit:

No, you can't change the address of an object. An instance of an object will live in exactly one place for the duration of its lifetime, until it is destroyed/deallocated.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping there would be some way to do this, but apparently not.

Comment: @KarlGiesing At most you design an outer-object which contains a shared_ptr to an inner-object which has all the actual data. Then assignment would cause multiple outers to point to the same inner. Obviously it's some extra work to set that up. And I would say it breaks a common C++ developer's expectation of what assignment means. So I would find it rather questionable to do, unless there is a very compelling use case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is okay, because even you assign this to another pointer, then the current object pointed by this will be memory leaked. Java has memory collection, but C++ not.

This is a good question, through. And this is possible.

```
A& operator=(const A& rhs)
{
    A * cthis = const_cast<A*>(this);
    cthis = const_cast<A*>(&rhs);
    return *cthis;
}
```

Edit: It is possible to change "this pointer" inside a member function. But changing "this pointer" doesn't accomplish much.

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't actually do anything meaningful besides `return *this;`. `this` is an rvalue, so you can't assign to it. `cthis` is a pointer, so assigning to it makes it point elsewhere.

Comment: @chris is correct. The cthis pointer is local to the function. All you're doing is saying "Make cthis point to this, then make it point to rhs." It doesn't alter what this points to.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done.  but, with pointer indirection.

Lets say you have a class someClass

```
class someClass
{
   someClass *someClsPtr;

   public:

   someClass(someClass *someClsPtrTemp):someClsPtr(someClsPtrTemp)
   {

   }

   someClass* operator=(someClass *someClsPtrTemp)
   {
       this->someClsPtr = someClsPtrTemp->someClsPtr;
       return this;
   }

   //now over load operator -> and operator *. Thats it.
};
```